# Anaconda Prompt and Navigator missing after install

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed latest anaconda in C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3.
But the navigator and prompt are missing after installation.
I tried to re-install(as administrator) and reboot the window 10 but it didn't work.

I also tried to delete registry of python which was under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE as written in following page.

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/#cannot-see-anaconda-menu-shortcuts-after-installation-on-windows

Running 'conda' in command prompt only shows it's not recognized as an internal or external command.

It seems like Anaconda is not installed but just creating bunch of python package in the folder.
Can someone share the idea?

My environment is Window 10 64bit

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned user variables in Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System settings -> Environment Variable. Re-installed latest Anaconda in https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/

Now Navigator and Prompt are showing correctly.